# How to set up touches regarding their location in view

Tags: sprite-kit, location

I'm making a game in SpriteKit. I have a left block and a right block there. At first I thought to use nodeAtPoint to interact with blocks but it's too uncomfortable for player in my case. I want to make such, that if player touches anywhere on the left side of the screen – it triggers left block, and right side of a screen triggers right block accordingly. How can one do like that?
 For now my code for interactions using nodes at point looks like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        switch self.nodeAtPoint(location) {
        case self.leftblock:
            println("closeleft")
            leftblock.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(leftArray, timePerFrame: 0.03, resize: true, restore: false))
        case self.rightblock:
            println("closeright")
            rightblock.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(rightArray, timePerFrame: 0.03, resize: true, restore: false))
        default: break
        }
    }
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        switch self.nodeAtPoint(location) {
        case self.leftblock:
            println("openleft")
            leftblock.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(reversedLeftArray, timePerFrame: 0.03, resize: true, restore: false))
        case self.rightblock:
            println("openright")
            rightblock.runAction(SKAction.animateWithTextures(reversedRightArray, timePerFrame: 0.03, resize: true, restore: false))
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A touch on the left side of the screen means that the `x coordinate of the location of the touch` will be less than `width / 2`. And for right side,
the `x coordinate of the location of the touch` will be greater than `width / 2`.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

   for touch in touches {

        let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        let middleOfScreen = (self.view?.frame.width)! / 2

        print(self.frame)

        print(middleOfScreen)
        print(touchPoint)

        if touchPoint.x < middleOfScreen {
            print("Clicked Left Side");
        } else {
            print("Clicked Right Side");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I expected! :)